# Opencart Forbidden access after swapping to previous database

Tags: opencart

Good day,

I had created my online store on a VPS, I opted to move the store to a web hosting package. After installing opecart using softalicioucs the default installation worked fine. I then edited the config files in both admin and public_html to change the database to the original backup of my VPS.

Once I do this, "*You don't have permission to access this resource. Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request*".

If I go back to the installed default database its all good again. I have set the necessary permissions etc for the user to access the backup database.

Anyone knows what is going on? is there some table storing access information?

Answer (score 1):

After disabling MODSECURE I realised that the new installation created tables with prefixes not as my original interfaces, hence the solution was to change the prefix in the config file.